# Delete whole line containing multiple words in command line

Tags: text, command-line, sed

I was trying to delete lines in a text which contain any word in a list. For example:

File 1:

```
xxx yyy, zzz,
aaa bbb, sss,
ccc fff, zzz,
rrr www, qasd,
```

File 2:

```
xxx
zzz
rrr
```

The target is to delete the lines in file1 which contain any word in file2.
So the output should be:

```
aaa bbb, sss,
```

I know how to use sed with single word, like sed '/zzz/d' to delete lines containing zzz. But how it works in multiple words, or words in a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
grep -vFwf file2 file1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with `grep`:

```
$ grep -Fwvf file2 file1
aaa bbb, sss,
```

Options:

> -f FILE, --file=FILE
>
> Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore
>             matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)
>
> -v, --invert-match
>
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)
>
> -w, --word-regexp
>
> Select only those lines containing matches that form  whole  words.   The  test  is  that  the
>                 matching  substring  must  either  be  at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word
>                 constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed  by  a
>                 non-word  constituent  character.   Word-constituent  characters  are letters, digits, and the
>                 underscore.
>
> -F, --fixed-strings
>
> Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of  which  is  to  be
>                 matched.  (-F is specified by POSIX.)

To store the changes back to `file1`:

```
$ grep -Fwvf file2 file1 > tmp && mv tmp file1
```

Comment: it's .. a little bit ... risky what about there is a line in file2 like 'r.r' or even 'r.*'

Comment: Then it wouldn't match @Kent your answer is identical but without the option explanation or the storing the changes back to file?

Comment: it will match, and mine is not identical before you fixing yours. now they are the same.

Comment: your fixed version should be ok. +1

Comment: the earlier one doesn't get the result, but this one works, thank you!

Comment: Sorry that adding explanation takes longer than simply posting code, there was a 60 second period where I adding the options with explanations from `man`.